# Where are the 'Spark Lock' challenges after you defeat Kaos in Woodborrow?

Tags: skylanders-swap-force

Where are the "Spark Lock" challenges located after you defeat Kaos in Woodborrow. A large treasure chest appears in the Great Hollow with a " - " above it, but it doesn't open and it does nothing.

Comment: Sorry to not have real answer, but I do have the same problem. All the online searching I have done has come up with nothing to fix this, all I can find is a lot of people saying this is problem with the wii version of swap force, apparently it should just open and does so on other platforms, no tricks to open it.

Answer (score 1):

To open the chest, just press the - button on your wii remote, then shake it fast. That's how you can open the treasure chest. Hope I could help!:)